# PHP e HTML5 maior valor entre 2 campos de formulário

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Como calcular valores de 2 campos do formulário antes de serem gravados no banco de dados e como gravar esse formulário? (Tudo na mesma página)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
include = ("bd.php"); //Conectando com o MySQL
?>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Registro de resultado dos jogos</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="estilos.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="site"> 
        <form method="post" id="insere_jgfeito" align="center" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!-- ÍNICIO DO USUÁRIO PREENCHENDO FORMULÁRIO -->

            <td>
            <tr>
                <span><strong>Inserir Resultados<strong></span>
            </br>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>
<select required name="campeonato"/>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Campeonato</option>
    <?php
        $cst_campeonato = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `campeonato` FROM `tbl_campeonatos` WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY `id` ASC");
            while($campeonatos = mysql_fetch_array($cst_campeonato)){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $campeonatos["id"];?>"><tr><?php echo $campeonatos["campeonato"];?></tr></option>
    <?php } ?>
<select>            </td></br>
            <td>
            <label for="data-atual">Realizado em...</label>
            <input type="date" name="data-atual" id="data-atual" value="<?=date('d/m/Y')?>" required>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </td></br>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <select required name="mandante"/>
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Mandante</option>
                <?php
                    $cst_competidor = mysql_query("SELECT `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` AS tecnico, `tbl_competidor`.`nome` AS nome FROM `tbl_competidor` INNER JOIN `tbl_jogadores` ON `tbl_competidor`.`id_competidor` = `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` WHERE `tbl_competidor`.`status` = 1 GROUP BY `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` ORDER BY `tbl_competidor`.`nome` ASC");
                    while($tecnicos = mysql_fetch_array($cst_competidor)){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $tecnicos["tecnico"];?>"><tr><?php echo $tecnicos["nome"];?></tr></option>
                <?php } ?>
            <select>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="9" name="mscore" required="required">
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="9" name="vscore" required="required">
            <select required name="visitante"/>
                <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Visitante</option>
                <?php
                    $cst_competidor = mysql_query("SELECT `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` AS tecnico, `tbl_competidor`.`nome` AS nome FROM `tbl_competidor` INNER JOIN `tbl_jogadores` ON `tbl_competidor`.`id_competidor` = `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` WHERE `tbl_competidor`.`status` = 1 GROUP BY `tbl_jogadores`.`tecnico` ORDER BY `tbl_competidor`.`nome` ASC");
                    while($tecnicos = mysql_fetch_array($cst_competidor)){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $tecnicos["tecnico"];?>"><tr><?php echo $tecnicos["nome"];?></tr></option>
                <?php } ?>
            <select>
            </td>
            </tr>   
            <input type="hidden" value="?" name="tipo"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="?" name="resultado"/>
            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="status"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="enviado" />
            <button type="submit">Gravar</button>
        </form> <!-- FIM DO FORMULÁRIO -->
    </div>
<?php 
/* RECEBENDO OS DADOS PREENCHIDOS DO FORMULÁRIO!
OBS: Para fins didáticos, todas as variavés utilizarão o prefixo "rcb_" referente a "recebe valor de" */

$rcb_campeonato = $_POST ["campeonato"];    // Captura o (select) com nome: "campeonato" referente ao "id_campeonato"
$rcb_data_atual = $_POST ["data-atual"];    // Traz (input date) com nome: "data-atual" 
$rcb_mandante   = $_POST ["mandante"];      // Captura o participante de nome: "mandante"
$rcb_mscore = $_POST ["mscore"];            // Recebe número entre 0 e 9 de: "mscore"
$rcb_vscore = $_POST ["vscore"];            // Recebe número entre 0 e 9 de: "vscore"
$rcb_visitante  = $_POST ["visitante"];     // Captura o participante de nome: "mandante"
$rcb_tipo   = $_POST ["tipo"];              // Campo oculto de valores 0=Empate, 1=Vitória do mandante ou 2=Visitante
$rcb_resultado = $_POST ["resultado"];      // Deve gravar o ID vencedor (mandante ou visitante) 
$rcb_status = $_POST ["status"];            // Se tudo estiver OK, grava sempre o campo com valor 1.


//Como gravar esses dados no banco de dados?


//Como referenciar a tabela do banco de dados?


$query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_jogos` ( `Null` , `id_campeonato`, `dt_partida` , `mandante` , `visitante` , `mscore` , `vscore` , `tipo` , `resultado`, `status`) 
VALUES ('$rcb_campeonato', '$rcb_data_atual', '$rcb_mandante', '$rcb_visitante', '$rcb_mscore', '$rcb_vscore', '$rcb_tipo', '$rcb_resultado', '$rcb_status')";

echo "Seu resultado foi gravado com sucesso!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo Silvio Sampaio, não deixe de marcar como aceita alguma resposta que venha a resolver seu problema. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em  https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Reverti sua pergunta à versão inicial. Caso tenha outras dúvidas diferentes desta, faça novas perguntas. Lembre-se de ler o guia de [ask] antes de qualquer coisa.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode usar javascript

```
<script>
 const mscore = document.querySelector('[name="mscore"]');
 const vscore = document.querySelector('[name="vscore"]');
 const hidden = document.querySelector('[name="resultado"]');

 const eventKeyup = () => {
     const mscoreVlr = parseInt(mscore.value);
     const  vscoreVlr = parseInt(vscore.value);
     if(mscoreVlr === vscoreVlr){
          //faça qualquer coisa
     }else{
         const maiorValor =   mscoreVlr > vscoreVlr 
                            ? mscore.value 
                            : vscore.value ;

        hidden.valeu = maiorValor;
    }


 };

mscore.addEventListener('keyup',eventKeyup);
vscore.addEventListener('keyup',eventKeyup);



</script>
```

Comment: Você observou o script que eu estava inserindo na tentativa de consultar quando os valores fossem iguais? O que caracterizaria o empate. Como envio o valor do javascript para o ID hidden de um form?

Comment: Mudei o script para adicionar o resultado ao input hidden, caso tenha o mesmo valor você pode fazer qualquer coisa